# Batch file - replact tokens from file

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple text file with some tokens

```
This is ${token1} and this is ${token2}
```

And another file with token values like

```
token1=me
token2=my brother
```

I found a way to achieve this using java code and library called freemarker
I was wondering if its simple enough to do using batch commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat) (it should be in the same directory as the script bellow):

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set "textFile=C:\text.txt"
set "propertiesFile=C:\properties.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("%propertiesFile%") do (
  call replacer.bat "%textFile%" "${%%a}" "%%b"
)

endlocal
```

with powershell :

```
@echo off
setlocal 
set "textFile=C:\text.txt"
set "propertiesFile=C:\properties.txt"

for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("%propertiesFile%") do (
  powershell "(Get-Content '%textFile%') -replace '\$\{%%a\}', '%%b' | Set-Content '%textFile%'"
)

endlocal
```

Comment: thank you for this but my company blocks VBS code and java, this is why i am trying with plain BATCH

Comment: @user648026  - how the VBS is blocked (thoght this is jscript but again it uses WSH) ?  Through the registry settings? Antivirus? What is the version of the windows machine (7,8,10) ? Is there installed powershell?

Comment: there is an active demon blocking it, its win 10 with powershell

Comment: should be something like powershell -Command "(gc myFile.txt) -replace 'foo', 'bar' | Out-File myFile.txt"       I will try it